# Qt - Help Linking Dynamic Library

Tags: c++, qt, dll, linker, dynamic-linking

I am having a ton of trouble with the simple task of linking a DLL to my Qt project.

My steps:

1. In Qt, I go to 'File -> New File or Project -> Other Project -> C++ Library'
2. Add a `calc` method to my **mylibrary.h**.
3. Implement the `calc` method in my **mylibrary.cpp**.
4. I compile, and I go to the directory where `.a` and `.dll` files were created.
5. I create a new project: 'File -> New File or Project -> Qt Widget Project -> Qt Gui Application'
6. I copy and paste all header files from MyLibrary to `C:/Users/Me/includes`, as well as `MyLibrary.dll` and `libMyLibrary.a` to `C:/Users/Me/`.
7. I then go into my Qt Widget Project's project file (step 5).

I add the include path as well as the DLL path:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Users/Me/includes"
LIBS += "C:/Users/Me/MyLibrary.dll"
```

I then go into my `mainwindow.cpp`, and put this code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include "mylibrary.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    MyLibrary myLib;
    qDebug() << myLib.calc();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

And of course, I get undefined errors:

```
C:\Users\Me\Desktop\TestInternals-Win\..\TestInternals\mainwindow.cpp:15: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN13MyLibrary4calcEv'

C:\Users\Me\Desktop\TestInternals-Win\..\TestInternals\mainwindow.cpp:15: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN13MyLibrary4calcEv'

:-1: error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

---

### MyLibrary File Contents

**mylibrary.h** contents:

```
#ifndef MYLIBRARY_H
#define MYLIBRARY_H

#include "MyLibrary_global.h"

class MYLIBRARYSHARED_EXPORT MyLibrary{
public:
    MyLibrary();
    int calc();
};

#endif // MYLIBRARY_H
```

**mylibrary.cpp** contents:

```
#include "mylibrary.h"

MyLibrary::MyLibrary()
{
}

int calc()
{
    return 5;
}
```

**I have not touched the Qt generated MyLibrary_global.h file**

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You suppose to link `MyLibrary.lib' instead of `MyLibrary.dll`?

Comment: I don't have a .lib, but I have a .a. I've tried linking the .a also, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: .a sosunds like it was compiled using gcc, not visual studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define a stand alone `calc` function instead of `MyLibrary::calc`, try:

mylibrary.cpp

```
#include "mylibrary.h"

MyLibrary::MyLibrary()
{
}

int MyLibrary::calc()
{
    return 5;
}
```